# Time tracking in Trello?

Tags: trello

In Trello, is there any way to get reporting of what tasks were in the "Doing" list in a given day or week, and how long they were there?

This would help with adding up billable hours, reporting time spent on projects to employers, etc.

Comment: Can you parse the activity log for that information?

Answer (score 8):

Trello does not currently have any time tracking or reporting features.

There is a [**proposal for a time tracking feature**](https://trello.com/c/9tX8CRNm) on the [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/dev).

Comment: It would be awesome to see a fogBugz-like time tracking for trello.

Comment: I demand time tracking in Trello. I'll even pay for it as an added feature. How is that for demand. :)

Comment: My boss told me "If they had time tracking in trello we could drop base-camp completely". I also agree with @user14403, lot's of people would pay for a good system like trello for managing projects.

Comment: There have been 409 upvotes for this feature on the Trello forum. Sounds like a mandate from the users to me.

Comment: @Laramie - If Trello is actually tracking this request somewhere else (e.g. Trello forum); it'd be good to get that link.

Comment: @Ben W It's now up to 509 votes (comments) here https://trello.com/card/time-tracking/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1054

Comment: Paydirt has just released a Chrome extension that adds time tracking to Trello. It adds a link to start a timer for the relevant client as you switch between boards.

See https://paydirtapp.com/time-tracking-in-trello for more info.

Comment: Dead link. Please post a valid one

Answer (score 0):

[Trello has an API](https://trello.com/docs/), and there are several blog posts about building your own features to do reporting.  There are also existing apps that interact with the API, like:

**ChartBreeze** (Trello charts and reporting) - http://www.chartbreeze.com

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used [Reports for Trello](http://reportsfortrello.com/), powerful and free to use.

Answer (score 0):

We have reviewed all the [Trello Time Tracking options here](https://www.bluecatreports.com/trello-reporting/time-tracking/). There are now a number of options that range from traditional time tracking tools where you record or manually add time to tasks and can generate timesheets from that. To tools that will generate reports on how long individual cards took to complete, or how long groups of cards took to complete. Take a look at the guide we wrote (we update it regularly) and pick the best option for you :)